# Can't able to convert old spacy 2.0 data to new spacy 3.0 acceptable format

Tags: spacy-3

i am trying convert old spacy 2.0 dataset to new spacy 3.0 acceptable format but i am getting this error "char_span() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alignment_mode' " error, How should i resolve this error?
i am using this code

```
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm
import spacy
from spacy.tokens import DocBin

nlp = spacy.blank("en") # load a new spacy model
db = DocBin() # create a DocBin object

for text, annot in tqdm(TRAIN_DATA): # data in previous format
    doc = nlp.make_doc(text) # create doc object from text
    ents = []
    for start, end, label in annot["entities"]: # add character indexes
        span = doc.char_span(start, end, label=label, alignment_mode="contract")
        if span is None:
            print("Skipping entity")
        else:
             ents.append(span)
    doc.ents = ents # label the text with the ents
    db.add(doc)

db.to_disk("./train.spacy") # save the docbin object
```

after running this script i am getting this error

TypeError: char_span() got an unexpected keyword argument 'alignment_mode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alignment_mode` option was added in spaCy v3, but you seem to be using spaCy v2. So if you run the above code with spaCy v3 it should work.

Comment: yeah it's working. i was using spacy v2.0 earlier but now with spacy v3.0 issue is resolved.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad it helped! When an answer is helpful, you can accept it by clicking the big checkmark to the left of it.